# AngularJS date sent to Spring back end is different (varies by a day)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, date

I have an AngularJS front end with a Java Spring back end. Whenever I send a date input in a form from the front end, the date is different in the back end.

For instance:

- AngularJS Input: September 28th
- Spring output: Tue Sep 27 20:00:00
  EDT 2016`

The date in the front end then shows September 27th. If I then send September 27th to the back end, it ends up being September 26th and so on.

Is there an issue with the way AngularJS and Spring format dates? Is there a timezone setting I need to mess with? Why is a day subtracted every time a date is sent?

**EDIT**

The date is simply an `ng-model` value which is then sent directly to a Spring controller into an object's date method. The date object I'm using is `java.util.Date`. Nothing else in between so no code is messing with the date or time zones. Is there some sort of time zone or date configuration that needs to be done for the date to be consistent?

I can provide my code if needed.

**EDIT 2**

Here's the input for the date:

```
<div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="date" name="startdate" ng-model="campaign.startDate"
            placeholder="Start Date" required="required" autocomplete="off" /> 
            <span class="error" style="color:red;" ng-show="myForm.startdate.$error.required">
                            Please enter your start date.</span>    
</div>
```

Just a simple date input field. In chrome, there's a date selector. Other browsers there isn't one.

Here's the upload controller that handles the date and other form data. A file is also uploaded, but that can be ignored. Everything is working apart from the date regressing 1 day.:

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, token, data ) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = token;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('data', data);

        $http.put(uploadUrl, formData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'Authentication':token
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status) {
            console.log("Successfully Uploaded");
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log("Error uploading");
        });
      }
```

Here's the modify controller where you can modify the date(both have the 1 day regression issue):

```
$scope.modifyCampaign = function(campaignId){
        var data = angular.toJson($scope.campaign);
        $http.post('/dashboard/modify/'+campaignId,data, {
            headers : {
                "content-type" : "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Successfully modified");
            $window.location.reload();
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error modifying");
        })
};
```

Spring controller for modifying a campaign:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/campaigns/modify/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<String> modifyCampaignData(
                                                 @PathVariable("id") long campaignId,
                                                 @RequestBody Campaign modifiedCampaign) {

      //This date here is 1 day behind the submitted date
      System.out.println("Start Date: " + modifiedCampaign.getStartDate());
```

The date isn't touched between sending it and receiving it, yet it's 1 day behind. This is what is leading me to believe it's a time zone issue but I'm stumped as to how to resolve it.

Comment: May be your application server is in different timezone

Comment: Looks like a locale inconsistency. It will help if you can show the code snippet where the date is generated/parsed on the front-end and the code snippet where you parse the date on the back-end.

Comment: Are you using a datepicker or something for entering the date? And how are you submitting to server, is that an AJAX? Are you able to see the value sent in the Dev toolbar ?

Comment: @NarainMittal Sending it using a simple input tag and sending that directly to the back end. I'll post the code for both in one second.

Comment: @Kyriakos I posted the code

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala I don't see why that'd be as they're both on the same machine currently. How would I configure the time zones so this won't happen?

Comment: How are you sending the Date to back-end  as string("2016-09-27") or long(milliseconds), if you are sending Date as string is there any DateFormatter

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala The date when printed out in the browser console is "2016-09-28". So no time. Do you think maybe it's adding `00:00` to the end of the date as time when it gets to the Java back end, and is set back a few hours due to a time zone difference? If it were set back a few hours from `2016-09-28 00:00` then it would go to the 27th? I'm just confused as to where I set the time zone settings for both Spring and AngularJS

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, because you are printing on application server, `Its always better to send date as milliseconds`.

Comment: You should be using DateFormatter to convert String date to Date, may be that is causing the issue

Comment: So you are sending to the backend the correct date ? When you look at your POST request in the browsers Netpanel can you tell how exactly the date looks like ?